# How to apply style rule based on selector using @if and @extend in SCSS?

Tags: css, sass

I want to apply a text-align property based on the selector name.

As you see below, I have tried using an `@if` directive with the selectors (these are two of four DOM elements), but this is ineffective.

All four DOM elements have text aligned to the right, so they are receiving the first code block in the `@if` statement.

This code block is nested within an `@extend` directive that is in turn put in the code blocks for each selector.

If this is not possible using this method, how would it be possible?

```
//global.scss

%project-title {
  @media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
      @if ("#project-1" or "#project-3") {
        text-align: right;
      } @else {
        text-align: left;
      }
   }
}

//_partial-1.scss

#project-1 {
  @extend project-title;
}

//_partial-2.scss

#project-3 {
  @extend project-title;
}
```

Comment: Why not make a mixin/function (i don't know what it is called in SCSS) and just pass the project number in and do the if/else that way?

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this should work. Be warned I have never used SCSS(only LESS), and a little googling helped me to write this but please check for syntax errors, specially the calling mixin part, I am not sure how mixin is called in SCSS, I gotta get going will update when I get back if this is wrong

```
@mixin project-title( $projectNumber ) {

   @if $projectNumber == '1' or $projectNumber == '3' {

      text-align: right;

   } @else {

      text-align: left;
   }
}

#project-1 {
  @include project-title(1);
}
```

A better idea is to add a left/right class and compare left and right instead of project number so it will for 100 projects or more. You would do comparison like

```
@if $projectNumber == 'left'
```

because if you have a whole bunch of project titles, the numbering way isn't going to work nicely

Comment: This solution isn't working, but thanks for the idea. If I can't come up with an all-in-one solution for `_global.scss`, like the %project-title above, then I'll try the mixin/function route.

Comment: Which part was not working? was it the call part? I updated with `@include` based on the docs, that should be the right way to call a mixin

Comment: Everything was aligned to the left. So the @if block wasn't hooking. I'm not certain it's possible inside the @extend directive. I think the only way is to apply so global styles inside `%project-title` and then individual styles for `text-align`...At least in my current architecture. It's too late in the process to redesign it, so I'll go with that.

Comment: Ok I don't have SCSS so can't really test it, but is this a layout where you got 2 columns so you want 1 and 3 to align right while the others align left? It may be easier if you used nth-child to handle this instead of the scss conditional statement

Comment: More or less...It's a media query layout with six columns. The text is an overlay for a project image. The subject of the image will be on one side and the text will be on the opposite side. I wanted to have a clean solution for this instead of repeating code, but I'm new-ish to conditionals and functions in SCSS. I'll give the nth-child approach a go.

Comment: I never even used SCSS but it sounds like nth-child should work. You might be over SCSSing it :)